# Proof by induction that $ \sum_{i=1}^n 3i-2 = \frac{n(3n-1)}{2} $

Tags: summation, proof-writing, induction, arithmetic-progressions

I'm starting to understand how induction works (with the whole $k \to k+1$ thing), but I'm not exactly sure how summations play a role. I'm a bit confused by this question specifically:

$$
\sum_{i=1}^n 3i-2 = \frac{n(3n-1)}{2}
$$

Any hints would be greatly appreciate

Comment: See also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1050814/prove-that-1-4-7-3n-%E2%88%92-2-frac-n3n-%E2%88%92-12

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Base case:**

- Let $n=1$ and test: $$\sum_{i=1}^1(3i-2)=3-2=1=\frac{1(3\cdot 1-1)}{2}$$
- True for $n = 1$

**Induction Hypothesis**:

- Assume that it is true for $k$: assume that $$\sum_{i=1}^k(3i-2)=\frac{k(3k-1)}{2}.$$

**Inductive Step:**

- Prove, using the Inductive Hypothesis as a premise, that $$\sum_{i=1}^{k+1}(3i-2)=\left(\sum_{i = 1}^k(3i - 2)\right) + (3(k+1)-2) = \frac{(k+1)(3(k+1)-1)}{2}.$$

Comment: So do I just manipulate the right side of the equation to try to get it to look like the original k(3k-1)/2 ?

Comment: No, manipulate the inner third (in the equality chain of last line) to get the right hand side. You know, from the inductive hypothesis, what that the sum $$\left(\sum_{i = 1}^k(3i - 2)\right) = \frac{k(3k - 1)}{2}.$$ Add that to the term $3(k+1)- 2$ to obtain the right hand side. The right hand side is precisely the form you want to exhibit to show that the given sum holds for $k+1$ if it holds for $k$, hence, you will have proven, by induction, that for all $n$, $$
\sum_{i=1}^n 3i-2 = \frac{n(3n-1)}{2}
$$

Comment: Ahh ok I think I understand now. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Sorry to bug you again, but I appear to be stuck. I've reached:

$$
(3k-2)+(3[k+1]-2)=\frac{k+1(3[k+1]-1)}{2}
$$
which I simplified to 
$$
12k-2=3k^2+5k+2
$$

Comment: That's exactly what you want: you want (k+1) in every spot where k occurs in the inductive hypothesis: i.e. you want the right hand side of my last line. That shows that what holds for k, holds when every k is replaced by (k+1): you want the same "form" as on the right hand side.

Comment: Oh so $12k-2=3k^2+5k+2$ is actually showing that? I must be a bit rusty with my algebra ;)

Comment: The first expression before simplified, is all you need to show. No need to simplify.

Comment: Oh okay. Thanks for all your help amWhy

Answer (score 2):

If we mimic amWhy's proof more generally we obtain a powerful result
on telescoping sums:

$$ \sum_{i=1}^n f(i) =?\  g(n)$$

**Base case:**

- Let $n=1$ and test: $$\sum_{i=1}^1 f(i) = f(1) \color{#c00}{=?}\ g(1)$$
- The $ $  Base Case $\ \,n = 1\ $ holds true $\iff \color{#C00}{f(1) = g(1)}$

**Induction Hypothesis**:

- Assume that it is true for $\, n = k$: assume that $$\sum_{i=1}^k f(i) = g(k).$$

**Inductive Step:**

- Prove, using the Induction Hypothesis as a premise, that $$\sum_{i=1}^{k+1}f(i)=\left(\sum_{i=1}^k f(i)\right) + f(k\!+\!1) = g(k) + f(k\!+\!1) \color{#0a0}{=?}\ g(k\!+\!1).$$
- The Inductive Step from $k$ to $k+1$ is true  $\iff \color{#0a0}{ g(k\!+\!1) - g(k) = f(k\!+\!1)}$

Therefore we have proved by induction the following generic summation criterion

$\displaystyle\quad\sum_{i=1}^n f(i) = g(n)\iff \color{#c00}{g(1) = f(1)}\,\ {\rm and}\,\ \color{#0a0}{g(n\!+\!1)-g(n) = f(n\!+\!1)}\ $ for $\,n \ge 1$

This theorem reduces the inductive proof to simply verifying the $\rm\color{#c00}{RHS}$ $\rm\color{#0a0}{equalities}$, which is trivial polynomial arithmetic when $f(n),g(n)$ are polynomials in $n,\,$ so trivial it can be done purely *mechanically* by a high-school student (or computer). No *insight* (magic) is required - no rabbits need be pulled from a hat.

The above theorem is an example of *telescopy*, also known as the *Fundamental Theorem of Difference Calculus*, depending on context. You can find [many more examples](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3a242%20telescopy&searchOn=3) of telescopy and related results in other answers here.

Answer (score 2):

I will prove it in two way for you:

1- Mathematical Induction:

If $n=1$ then the left side is $1$ and also the right side is $1$ too.

Now think that we have $\sum_{i=1}^{n}(3i-2)=\frac{n(3n-1)}{2}$, we should show $\sum_{i=1}^{n+1}(3i-2)=\frac{(n+1)(3(n+1)-1)}{2}$ that is $\sum_{i=1}^{n+1}(3i-2)=\frac{(n+1)(3n+2)}{2}$. But we can write;
$$\sum_{i=1}^{n+1}(3i-2)=(\sum_{i=1}^{n}(3i-2))+(3(n+1)-2)=\frac{n(3n-1)}{2}+(3n+1)=\frac{3n^{2}-n+6n+2}{2}=\frac{3n^{2}+5n+2}{2}=\frac{3n^{2}+3n+2n+2}{2}=\frac{3n(n+1)+2(n+1)}{2}=\frac{(n+1)(3n+2)}{2}$$.
And it finished our work.

2- Without Mathematical Induction:

We know $\sum_{i=1}^{k}i=\frac{k(k+1)}{2}$ and $\sum_{i=1}^{k}c=kc$ for a constant number "c".

Now $$\sum_{i=1}^{n}(3i-2)=3\sum_{i=1}^{n}i-\sum_{i=1}^{n}2=3\frac{n(n+1)}{2}-2n=\frac{n(3n+3-4)}{2}=\frac{n(3n-1)}{2}$$.

Answer (score 1):

For $n=1$ you have $\sum_{i=1}^1(3i-2)=3-2=1=\frac{1(3\cdot 1-1)}{2}$.

Suppose that $$\sum_{i=1}^n(3i-2)=\frac{n(3n-1)}{2}$$ and prove that $$\sum_{i=1}^{n+1}(3i-2)=\frac{(n+1)(3(n+1)-1)}{2}.$$