# Prove by Mathematical Induction: $1(1!) + 2(2!) + \cdot \cdot \cdot +n(n!) = (n+1)!-1$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, summation, induction, factorial

Prove by Mathematical Induction . . .

$1(1!) + 2(2!) + \cdot \cdot \cdot +n(n!) = (n+1)!-1$

I tried solving it, but I got stuck near the end . . .

a. Basis Step:

> $(1)(1!) = (1+1)!-1$
>
> $1 = (2\cdot1)-1$
>
> $1 = 1 \checkmark$

b. Inductive Hypothesis

> $1(1!) + 2(2!) + \cdot \cdot \cdot +k(k!) = (k+1)!-1$

Prove k+1 is true.

> $1(1!) + 2(2!) + \cdot \cdot \cdot +(k+1)(k+1)! = (k+2)!-1$
>
> $\big[RHS\big]$
>
> $(k+2)!-1 = (k+2)(k+1)k!-1$
>
> $\big[LHS\big]$
>
> $=\underbrace{1(1!) + 2(2!) + \cdot \cdot \cdot + k(k+1)!} + (k+1)(k+1)!$ (Explicit Last Step)
>
> $= \underbrace{(k+1)!-1}+(k+1)(k+1)!$ (Inductive Hypothesis Substitution)
>
> $= (k+1)!-1 + (k+1)(k+1)k!$
>
> $= (k+1)k!-1 + (k+1)^{2}k!$

My [LHS] looks nothing like my [RHS] did I do something wrong?

EDIT:

> $ = (k+1)k! + (k+1)^2k! -1 $
>
> $ = (k+1)(k!)(1 + (k+1))-1$
>
> $ = (k+1)(k!)(k+2)-1 = (k+2)(k+1)k!-1$

Comment: I like the name *Mathematica Induciton*.

Comment: my mistake . . .

Comment: Under this section, how do you get the 2nd line? In particular the (1 +(k+1)). EDIT: =(k+1)k!+(k+1)2k!−1
=(k+1)(k!)(1+(k+1))−1
=(k+1)(k!)(k+2)−1=(k+2)(k+1)k!−1

Comment: $(k+1)k!+(k+1)^{2}k!-1$

Comment: How does one get the 2nd line? How do you go from addition to multiplication?

Comment: I see now you factored it out.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your LHS may not look much like your RHS yet, but that's because you haven't finished getting it into the simplest possible form.  You have $(k+1)k! - 1 + (k+1)^2 k!$.  You're looking to get something minus $1$, so that's somewhat promising.  Now what factors do the other two terms (the ones involving $k$) have in common?

Comment: ah! thanks i figured it out!

Comment: It looks odd now that you edited the question, so that my answer looks like I didn't see the whole thing or something.  But anyway, the main thing is, you figured it out. =]

Answer (score 5):

It's a special case of *telescopic* induction. [This post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/286362/23500) has a very short and simple inductive proof of

**Theorem** $\rm\displaystyle\,\ \sum_{i\,=\,1}^n f(i) = g(n)\iff g(1) = f(1)\ {\rm and}\ g(n\!+\!1)-g(n) = f(n\!+\!1)\ $ for $\,n \ge 1.$

Applied to your case, where $\rm\,f(n) = n n!\:$ and $\rm\:g(n) = (n+1)!-1,\,$ we have $\rm\: g(1)=1 = f(1),\:$ and

$$\begin{eqnarray}\rm g(n\!+\!1)-g(n) &=&\rm (n\!+\!2)!-1-((n\!+\!1)!-1) \\
 &=&\rm (n\!+\!2)!\,-\,(n\!+\!1)! \\
 &=&\rm (n\!+\!2 -1)(n\!+\!1)! \\
 &=&\rm (n\!+\!1)(n\!+\!1)! \\
 &=&\rm f(n\!+\!1) \end{eqnarray}$$

That completes the proof using the theorem. This method works quite widely for inductive proofs involving sums and products. You can find [many more examples](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A242+telescopy) of telescopy and related results in other answers here.

Comment: thanks for the insight. i will study this more.

Answer (score 4):

$$1(1!) + 2(2!) + \cdot \cdot \cdot +n(n!) = (n+1)!-1$$
then
$$1(1!) + 2(2!) + \cdot \cdot \cdot +n(n!)+(n+1)(n+1)! =(n+1)!-1+(n+1)(n+1)!=$$
$$(n+1)!(n+1+1)-1=(n+2)!-1=((n+1)+1)!-1$$

Comment: wow thanks! . . . this looks like a much shorter solution, but i wonder if i will get in trouble for not using k and not invoking the inductive hypothesis step. anyway i will practice this as an alternative.

Answer (score 2):

There is a mistake in the [LHS], it should look like this:

$$
\underbrace{1(1!) + \ldots + k(k!)}_{=(k+1)! - 1} + (k+1)(k+1)! = \ldots
$$