# How to simplify the summation kk! without using induction?

Tags: combinatorics, summation, factorial

$$\sum_{k=1}^nk(k!)$$

I know the answer is (n+1)!-1..I can solve this question using principle of mathematical induction...but I would like to know if there is any other alternative approach

Comment: A direct approach would use $$k!=\int_0^\infty x^ke^{-x}~\mathrm dx$$

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt Direct?? Come on! There is nothing in the problem to suggest any integrals.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen There is nothing to suggest I can't use integrals. The OP is asking for alternative approaches, what is wrong with this?

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt: I think Marc was objecting to calling it "direct". It doesn't look very direct to me either.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt Nothing wrong with the approach (provided it leads somewhere). It just isn't _direct_ by my book. A direct approach does not use an auxiliary device.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Oh, sorry. Perhaps the "would" should be replaced with "could". Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Related (as well as all the links in this one): https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/301615/prove-by-mathematical-induction-11-22-cdot-cdot-cdot-nn-n However, most involve induction.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt: It would be useful if you could write an answer with a more complete explanation of your approach. I can follow you as far as getting to $nx^n+\cdots+3x^3+2x^2+x$. This equals $x\frac{d}{dx}(\frac{x^{n+1}-1}{x-1})$ which at least has an $x^{n+1}-1$ in it, but how do you get it out? Integration by parts?

Comment: @HenningMakholm As you wish.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Write $k(k!)=((k+1)-1)k!=(k+1)!-k!$. Now your sum telescopes
$$
  \sum_{k=1}^nk(k!) = \sum_{k=1}^n\Bigl((k+1)!-k!\Bigr)=(n+1)!-1!=(n+1)!-1.
$$

Answer (score 5):

Set a permutation $\pi = \pi_1 \ldots \pi_{n+1}$ in $S_{n+1}$.

Now let $m = m(\pi)$ be the maximal index such that $\pi_1 = 1, \pi_2 = 2, \ldots, \pi_m = m$.

The number of permutations such that $m(\pi) = m$ for $m < n$ is $(n-m) (n-m)!$: now $n-m$ is the number of choices for $\pi_{m+1} \neq m+1$, and $(n-m)!$ is the number of permutations of the remaining $n-m$ numbers.

No permutation can satisfy $m(\pi) = n$, and there is only one permutation such that $m(\pi) = n+1$.

Since there are $(n+1)!$ permutations in $S_{n+1}$, one has

$$ (n+1)! = \sum_{m=0}^{n-1} (n-m)(n-m)! + 1 = \sum_{k=1}^n k \cdot k! + 1. $$

Answer (score 4):

Observe that
$$
k (k!) = (k+1)! - k!
$$
and write the sum as a telescopic sum:
$$
\sum_{k=1}^n k (k!) = \sum_{k=1}^n [ (k+1)! - k!] = (n+1)! - 1.
$$

Answer (score 4):

$$\sum_{k=1}^nk\cdot k!=\sum_{k=1}^n [(k+1)-1]k!=\sum_{k=1}^n(k+1)!-k!$$
This is a telescoping sum:
$$
{2!}-1!+{3!}-{2!}+{4!}-{3!}+\dots+(n+1)!-{n!}=
$$
$$
\not{2!}-1!+\not{3!}-\not{2!}+\not{4!}-\not{3!}+\dots+(n+1)!-\not{n!}=(n+1)!-1!
$$

Answer (score 4):

By the integral representation of the factorial, this becomes

$$S=\int_0^\infty\sum_{k=0}^nkx^ke^{-x}~\mathrm dx$$

By geometric series and its derivative,

$$S=\int_0^\infty xe^{-x}\frac\partial{\partial x}\frac{1-x^{n+1}}{1-x}~\mathrm dx$$

Integrate by parts,

$$S=\int_0^\infty e^{-x}(x^{n+1}-1)~\mathrm dx$$

And reapply the integral representation of the factorial to finish off with

$$S=(n+1)!-0!$$

Answer (score -1):

Add to the sum $1!+2!+3!+\ldots+n!=\sum _{k=1}^n k!$

You get

$(1+1!)+(2\times2! + 2!) + (3\times 3!+3!)+\ldots +(n\times n!+n!)=\\=2! +2! (2+1)+3!(3+1)+\ldots+n!(n+1)=2!+3!+4!+\ldots+(n+1)!$

Now subtract $1!+2!+3!+\ldots+n!=\sum _{k=1}^n k!$

You have $2!+3!+4!+\ldots+(n+1)! - 1!-2!-3!-\ldots-n!=(n+1)!-1$

Comment: This looks like induction to me.

Comment: @PeterTaylor No! I just added and subtracted quantities: it's absolutely induction-free! I realized jist now that it's very similar to another answer

Comment: You added and subtracted quantities *in order* to show that given that it holds for $n$, it holds for $n+1$. What is that if not a proof of the inductive step?

Comment: @Peter Taylor If you are convinced of this go and comment also Mike Earnest's answer because my answer is very similar to Mike's

Comment: @Raffaele Mike's answer relies on telescoping, which is generally considered 'obvious', hence, no induction. Your's does not.