# Finding the formula for the sum of a the sequence $1 + 4 + 7 + ... + (3n + 1)$

Tags: summation, induction, arithmetic-progressions

In the problem below, It is asked to find the formula for the sum of the sequence and then to prove whether it is true or false for all *n* values using induction.

$$ 1 + 4 + 7 + ... + (3n + 1), \ n\in \Bbb N_0$$

In order to do that I tried to convert it into Sigma notation

$$\sum_{n=0}^k 3n + 1 $$

and then using the rules of sigma notation I came up with

$$\sum_{n=0}^k 3n + 1 = 3\cdot \sum_{n=0}^k n + \sum_{n=0}^k 1$$

and then I replaced it with the following to come to the formula for the sum of the sequence

$$3\cdot\frac{n(n+1)}{2} + (n + 1) = \frac{(n+1)(3n+2)}{2}$$

But it seems to be totally incorrect!

What am I doing wrong. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I added the simplification. Thanks.

Comment: There is still the problem I referred to earlier, your sum should be $\sum_{k=0}^n(3k+1)$. And if induction is asked for, you need to use another approach.

Comment: The problem has two parts. The first part is to find a formula for the sum of the sequence. The second part is to prove it using induction. I think if I replace _n_ with _k_ the problem that you referred to is solved. You are also right about the brackets around the expression.

Comment: If we will use induction, then by tradition one goes from the case $n=k$ to the case $n=k+1$. Then one would use something lime $\sum_{i=1}^n$, or $\sum_{i=1}^k$ to avoid confusion.

Comment: That's right. Thanks for the hint.

Comment: See also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/286312/proof-by-induction-that-sum-i-1n-3i-2-fracn3n-12 and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1050814/prove-that-1-4-7-3n-%E2%88%92-2-frac-n3n-%E2%88%92-12

Comment: It does work!  n=0 => 1, n=1 => 5 = 1 + 4, n = 2 => 12 = 1 + 4 + 7, etc.

Comment: ...but you didn't do it by induction.  (which I *hate* to criticize you on as direct proofs are more satisfying to me).

Answer (score 1):

Looks good! You should add brackets in this sum 
$$
\sum_{n=0}^k (3n+1)
$$
to clarify whether the $+1$ summand belongs to the sum.

Answer (score 0):

Your answer looks just fine, although you changed the role that $n$ plays in your formula half-way through the post.

Comment: I think you mean by the final result I should replace _n_ with _k_. Am I right?

Answer (score 0):

I think you may be confused with what k should be. If you have m terms, then k = m-1. For example, if you have 3 terms 1, 4 and 7, k should be 2 not 3.