# $\sum_{j=1}^n(3j - 2) = \frac{n(3n - 1)}{2} $ using geometry

Tags: sequences-and-series

I know how to prove it by induction, but is there a way using geometry?
I tried to use triangles to get the half but can't proceed.

Comment: For other proofs than induction see [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1050814/prove-that-1-4-7-3n-%E2%88%92-2-frac-n3n-%E2%88%92-12?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Imagine that you have $n$ rectangles of dimensions $1\times(3j-2)$ for $j=1,2,\ldots,n$. Arrange them in a sort of staircase, like this for $n=3$:

```
*
****
*******
```

Now make a second copy, but upside down:

```
*******
   ****
      *
```

Finally, slide the two together to make an $n\times(3n-1)$ rectangle:

```
*|*******
****|****
*******|*
```

Here I’ve left vertical bars between the two ‘staircases’ to make the construction clear, but of course they should be removed.

Answer (score 1):

Not completely geometric.. but without Induction

$$
\sum_{j=1}^n(3j - 2) = \sum_{j=1}^n 3j - \sum_{j=1}^n 2 = 3\sum_{j=1}^n j - 2\sum_{j=1}^n 1
$$
Now,
$\sum_{j=1}^n 1$ is $n$ and 
$$
\sum_{j=1}^n j 
$$
could be represented in geometry, for example for n=3 i.e. 1 + 2 + 3

```
***
**
*
```

which is half of square of $3X3$ (*s) + half of # of diagonal elements (as they are considered half while considering identity as half of square).

Hence,
$$
\sum_{j=1}^n j  = \frac{n^2}{2} + \frac{n}{2} =\frac{n(n+1)}{2}
$$

Finally,
$$
\sum_{j=1}^n(3j - 2) = \frac{3n(n+1)}{2} - 2n = \frac{n(3n - 1)}{2}
$$

Comment: Thanks, I like this answer too, I'll give you a +1. But I will accept the other one because is more of what I was looking for.