# Different proofs of $\,a^n-b^n =(a-b)\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} a^i b^{n-1-i} $?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, induction, alternative-proof, big-list

How many different proofs are there that
$a^n-b^n
=(a-b)\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} a^i b^{n-1-i}
$
for positive integer $n$
and real $a, b$?

You can use any techniques you want.
My proof just uses algebra,
summation, and induction,
but if you want to use invariant sheaves
over covalent topologies,
that is fine.

I decided that
I would try to produce
a proof by induction.
I find it interesting that
my proof shows that
if it is true for
$n-1$,
then it is true for $n+1$.
This means that two base cases
have to be proven:
$n=1$ and $n=2$.
Fortunately,
those are easy.

I am sure that my proof is known, 
but I do not recall having seen it before.

Here is the induction step:

$\begin{array}\\
a^{n+1}-b^{n+1}
&=a^{n+1}-a^nb+a^nb-b^{n+1}\\
&=a^{n+1}-a^nb +a^nb-ab^n +ab^n-b^{n+1}\\ 
&=(a-b)a^n +ab(a^{n-1}-b^{n-1}) +(a-b)b^n\\ 
&=(a-b)(a^n+b^n) +ab(a^{n-1}-b^{n-1}) \\ 
&=(a-b)(a^n+b^n) +ab((a-b)\sum_{i=0}^{n-2} a^i b^{n-2-i})
\ \  \text{(The induction hypothesis)} \\ 
&=(a-b)(a^n+b^n+ab\sum_{i=0}^{n-2} a^i b^{n-2-i}) \\ 
&=(a-b)(a^n+b^n+\sum_{i=0}^{n-2} a^{i+1} b^{n-1-i}) \\ 
&=(a-b)(a^n+b^n+\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} a^{i} b^{n-i}) \\ 
&=(a-b)\sum_{i=0}^{n} a^{i} b^{n-i} \\ 
\end{array}
$

Comment: Just expand the right hand side and cancel everything in sight. Induction is overkill. (Also, in general induction will only work if you already know one side of some equation. What happens when you really want to *find* some expression?)

Comment: There's no reason to force $a,b$ to be real; might as well make them indeterminates in the polynomial ring $\Bbb Z[x,y]$. Then you can just tensor and evaluate as needed.

Comment: Alternative proof: Take the usual geometric series $a^n-1=(a-1) \sum_{i<n} a^i$, now homogenize.

Comment: I certainly know about the usual multiply and cancel proof. I just wanted to see if I could prove it by induction. Also, I wonder if there is a proof by induction that goes from n to n+1, rather than n-1 to n+1.

Comment: @Martin The (inductive!) cancellation is a prototypical application of *telescopy* - see my answer.

Comment: [Here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/900900/combinatorial-proof-of-an-bn-a-ban-1-an-2b-dots-ab/900982#900982) for proofs using combinatorial arguments

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By [telescopy](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/855703/242) $\ f_n = x^n\,\Rightarrow  \displaystyle \overbrace{f_n-f_0 =\sum_{k\,=\,0}^{n-1}\left[f_{k+1}\:\!-\:\!f_k\right]}^{\textstyle\ \ x^{n} - 1 \:\!=\:\! \sum\ {\overbrace{[x^{k+1}-{x^k}^{\phantom |}\!}^{\Large \color{#0a0}{(x\,-\,1)}\,\color{#c00}{x^k}\!\!}]}_{\phantom{|_|}}} =\, \color{#0a0}{(x\!-\!1)}\sum_{k\,=\,0}^{n-1}\, \color{#c00}{x^k} $

The sought result (*Factor Theorem*) follows by [homogenization,](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/20332/242) i.e.  $\, x\to a/b\,$ then scale by $\,b^n.$

**Remark** $\ $ The simple theorem employed to evaluate the above telescopic sum may be viewed as a discrete analog of the Fundamental Theorem of Integral Calculus

$$\begin{eqnarray} f &=& \sum \Delta f,\quad \Delta f(n) = f(n+1) -f(n)\\
f & =& \ \int D f,\quad D\, f(x) = f'(x)\end{eqnarray}$$

However, [the proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/286362/242) of the discrete analog  (the Fundamental Theorem of *Difference* Calculus) is just a trivial one-line induction exploiting telescopic cancellation.

Comment: See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2346835/242) for more on the telescopic view of this proof.

Answer (score 2):

Using
$$\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}x^k={1-x^n\over1-x}$$
we get
\begin{align}
a^n-b^n
&=a^n\left[1-\left({b \over a}\right)^n\right]\\
&=a^n\left[1-{b \over a}\right]\sum^{n-1}_{k=0}{b^k\over a^k}\\
&=\sum^{n-1}_{k=0}a^{n-k}b^k-\sum^{n-1}_{k=0}a^{n-k-1}b^{k+1}\\
&=(a-b)\sum^{n-1}_{k=0}a^{n-k-1}b^k
\end{align}

Comment: i.e. use **homegenization** to deduce the bivariate case from the univariate case - see the links in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

$P(x)=x^n-1$ has the root $x=1$ so it factors as $P(x) = (x-1)Q(x)$. Differentiating the product $k \lt n$ times with the [Leibniz rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_Leibniz_rule) and using that $(x-1)^{(j)} = 0$ for $j \ge 2\,$:

$$
n(n-1)\dots(n-k+1)\,x^{n-k} = (x-1)Q^{(k)}(x) + \binom{k}{1} Q^{(k-1)}(x)
$$

Setting $\,x=0\,$ gives $\,Q^{k}(0)=k\,Q^{(k-1)}(0)\,$, so by induction $\,Q^{(k)}(0) = k!\,$, then by [Taylor's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor%27s_theorem#Statement_of_the_theorem):

$$
Q(x) = \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \frac{Q^{(k)}(0)}{k!}\,x^k = \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \,x^k \quad\iff\quad x^n-1 = (x-1)\left(1 + x + \dots+x^{n-1}\right)
$$

[Homogenizing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homogeneous_polynomial#Homogenization) the latter equality produces the title identity.