# If $\gcd(a,b)=1$, is $\gcd(a^x-b^x,a^y-b^y)=a^{\gcd(x,y)}-b^{\gcd(x,y)}$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

If $\gcd(a,b)=1$, is it true that
$$\gcd(a^x-b^x,a^y-b^y)=a^{\gcd(x,y)}-b^{\gcd(x,y)}\;?$$

I know that $a^{\gcd(x,y)}-b^{\gcd(x,y)}\mid a^x-b^x$ and $a^{\gcd(x,y)}-b^{\gcd(x,y)}|a^y-b^y$, so I thought of something like let $n$ be a divisor of  $a^x-b^x$ and $a^y-b^y$, then $n$ must also be a divisor of $a^{\gcd(x,y)}-b^{\gcd(x,y)}$ but I am stuck.

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/7473/prove-that-gcdan-1-am-1-a-gcdn-m-1

Comment: I already know this result, I am looking for a generalization.

Comment: It clearly fails for $b = 0$, at least.

Comment: and you can see also that $gcd(a,b)^{\min(x,y)}$ divides both of the terms, and does not divide $a^{gcd(x,y)}-b^{gcd(x,y)}$ so as a conclusion the main equation is not correct

Comment: Notice the proper use of \gcd and \mid in my edit.  Both result in proper spacing.  Notice the difference between $a|b$ and $a\mid b$; the latter uses \mid.  And in $a\gcd(b,c)$, if I had written a gcd(b,c) instead of a\gcd(b,c), then you would have seen $a gcd(b,c)$ instead of  $a\gcd(b,c)$. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @Elaqqad : You should also notice my comment above.

Comment: @Elaqqad forgot to specify: $\gcd(a,b)=1$.

Comment: Can anyone tell me if my answer is correct?

Comment: @anomaly but $\gcd(a, 0) = |a| \not = 1$

Answer (score 3):

$\ (a,b)=1\Rightarrow (b,a^n\!-b^n) = (b,a^n) = 1$ so $\,\color{#c00}{b\ {\rm is\ coprime}}$ to $\,a^x\!-b^x,\,a^y\!-b^y\,$  so coprime to any common divisor $\,d.\,$  So $\,{\rm mod}\ d\!:\, c = a/b = a\color{#c00}{b^{-1}\rm\ exists}$, so $\,a^n\equiv b^n\!\!\iff\! c^n =(a/b)^n\!\equiv 1\,$ so

$$c^x\equiv 1\equiv c^y\iff {\rm ord}\, c\mid x,y\iff {\rm ord}\, c\mid(x,y)=:g\iff c^g\equiv 1\quad {\bf QED}$$

where the first & third $\!\iff\!$ is by the [Order Theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/127118/242) and the second is the [gcd Universal Property](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/198801/242).

**Remark** $ $ This [method](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/901264/242) of reducing a proof about a homogeneous polynomial to a simpler nonhomogeneous case often proves handy.

Comment: What's ord $c$? Do you mean $c^n \equiv 1$ mod $d$? With $(a/b)^n$ do you mean $a^n*(b^{-1})^n$?

Comment: @wow $\ {\rm ord}\, c\,$ is the least $\,k>0\,$ such that  $\,c^k\equiv 1.\,$ Then $\, c^n\equiv 1\iff {\rm ord}\, c\mid n.\ $ $\ c := a/b = ab^{-1}\ \ $

Comment: Ok and you are working mod $d$?

Comment: @wow yes, all congruences are mod $\,d,\,$ where $\,d\,$ is any common divisor of $\,a^x-b^x,\, a^y-b^y.\ $ I edited the answer clarify it a bit. Please feel welcome to ask further questions.

Comment: Ok thank you it is fully clear now. Can you look at my answer and tell me if it is correct?

Answer (score 1):

To prove:
if $a^x \equiv b^x$ mod $n$ and $a^y \equiv b^y$ mod $n$, then
$a^{gcd(x,y)} \equiv b^{gcd(x,y)}$ mod $n$.

($\gcd(a,b)=1$)

Let $d=\gcd(x,y)$, $x=p*d$, $y=q*d$, then $\gcd(p,q)=1$ so there exists $m,o > 0$ so that $po=1+qm$ or vice versa.
Let $y>x$.

$(a^d)^{po} \equiv (b^d)^{po}$ mod $n$, so
$(a^d)^{1+qm} \equiv (b^d)^{1+qm}$ mod $n$, so
$a^d*(a^{dq})^m \equiv b^d*(b^{dq})^m$ mod $n$
so $a^d \equiv b^d$ mod $n$,
so every $n$ that divides both $a^x-b^x$ and $a^y-b^y$ also divides $a^d-b^d$, so $\gcd(a^x-b^x,a^y-b^y)=a^{\gcd(x,y)}-b^{\gcd(x,y)}$

Comment: Here's the proof using $\,x,y\,$ vs. $\,pd,qd$

$$\begin{align} a^x\equiv b^x\, \Rightarrow&\quad\ \ \ a^{ox}\equiv b^{oy}\\
\Rightarrow&\ \ a^{d+my}\equiv b^{d+my}\\
\Rightarrow&\ \ a^d (a^y)^m\equiv b^d (b^y)^m\\
\Rightarrow&\ \ a^d (a^y)^m\equiv b^d (a^y)^m\,\ {\rm by}\,\ b^y\equiv a^y\\
\Rightarrow&\ \ a^d \equiv b^d\,\ {\rm by\ cancel}\,\ a^{ym}
\end{align}$$ 
Looks good, except you need to prove $\,(a,n)=1\,$ to be able to cancel $\,a.\,$ Also, you should probably say more about how you use this to get the gcd equality.

Comment: Nice, it is very similar. $(a,n)=1$, because $(a,n)|(a,a^x-b^x)=1$ because $(a,b)=1$. I don't understand what you mean? I'm saying every $n$ that divides both $a^x-b^x$ and $a^y-b^y$ will also divide $a^d-b^d$, so $(a^x-b^x,a^y-b^y) | a^d-b^d$ but $a^d-b^d|(a^x-b^x,a^y-b^y)$ so $a^d-b^d=(a^x-b^x,a^y-b^y)$