# Is this a valid proof for $\gcd(a^m - b^m, a^n - b^n) = a^{\gcd(m, n)} - b^{\gcd(m,n)}$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, solution-verification

$ \newcommand{\Mod}[1]{\ (\mathrm{mod}\ #1)} $

> Prove that, if $\gcd(a,b)=1$ and $a>b>0$, then $$
>      \gcd(a^m - b^m, a^n - b^n) = a^{\gcd(m, n)} - b^{\gcd(m,n)}, \quad 0 \leq m < n . $$ (All variables are integers.)

Let $d>0$ be an integer so that $d = \gcd(a^m - b^m, a^n - b^n)$ and therefore, by definition, $d \backslash (a^m - b^m)$, $d \backslash (a^n - b^n)$.

By definition of modular congruence, if $m > 0$, then $a \equiv b \Mod{m}$ if and only if $m \backslash (b - a)$, we get
\begin{equation*}
    b^m \equiv a^m \Mod{d} \; , \quad
    b^n \equiv a^n \Mod{d} \; .
\end{equation*}
According to the Bézout's lemma, there must exist integers $x$ and $y$ so that $mx + ny = \gcd(m, n)$.

We can raise both sides to the power of $x$ or $y$:
\begin{equation*}
    (b^m)^x \equiv (a^m)^x \Mod{d} \; , \quad 
    (b^n)^y \equiv (a^n)^y \Mod{d} \; .
\end{equation*}
We can "combine" and simplify them as following:
\begin{gather*} 
    (b^m)^x \cdot (b^n)^y \equiv (a^m)^x \cdot (a^n)^y \Mod{d} \; , \\
    b^{mx + ny} \equiv a^{mx+ny} \Mod{d} \; ,
\end{gather*}
and further as
\begin{equation*}
    b^{\gcd(m, n)} \equiv a^{\gcd(m,n)} \Mod{d} \;.
\end{equation*}
If follows that
\begin{equation}
    d \backslash (a^{\gcd(m,n)} - b^{\gcd(m, n)}) \; . \tag{1}
\end{equation}
Moreover, we can factor
\begin{gather*} 
    a^n - b^n = (a^{\gcd(m,n)} - b^{\gcd(m,n)})(a^{n-\gcd(m,n)}b^0 + a^{n-\gcd(m,n)-1}b^1 + \ldots + a^0 b^{n-\gcd(m,n)}) \;, \\
    a^m - b^m = (a^{\gcd(m,n)} - b^{\gcd(m,n)})(a^{m-\gcd(m,n)}b^0 + a^{m-\gcd(m,n)-1}b^1 + \ldots + a^0 b^{m-\gcd(m,n)}) \; .
\end{gather*}
Here we can see that $(a^{\gcd(m,n)} - b^{\gcd(m,n)}) \backslash (a^n - b^n)$, $(a^{\gcd(m,n)} - b^{\gcd(m,n)}) \backslash (a^m - b^m)$, and therefore
\begin{equation}
    (a^{\gcd(m,n)} - b^{\gcd(m,n)}) \backslash \gcd(a^m - b^m, a^n - b^n) \;. \tag{2}
\end{equation}
(1) and (2) together imply
\begin{equation*}
    \gcd(a^m - b^m, a^n - b^n) = a^{\gcd(m, n)} - b^{\gcd(m,n)} \; .
\end{equation*}

Comment: In the first half the expts $x,y$ can be negative so you need to prove that $a,b$ are invertible $\!\bmod d$, i.e,. coprime to $d$. Then 2nd half is a special case of the [Factor Theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/17793/242).

Comment: The proof is more *conceptual* by first proving the [homogeneous case](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/901264/242), which is obvious using properties of *multiplicative order*, e.g. as done [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1217689/242).

Comment: Good job with the duplicates @BillDubuque.

Comment: Oops. prior comment should say "**non**-homogeneous" case. @Jyrki Thanks.

Comment: @BillDubuque Probably a stupid question, but I'm having trouble understanding why it follows from $gcd(a,b)=1$ that $gcd(a, d)=gcd(b, d)=1$ given $d = \gcd(a^m−b^m,a^n−b^n)$.

Comment: That proof is in the answer I linked in my first comment above.(hint: use Euclidean algorithm modular reduction of gcd, then Euclid's lemma)