# Prove by induction that $1+4+7+...+(3n-2) = 2n(3n-1)$

Tags: summation, induction

I have an exercise where I, using induction, have to prove the following:

\begin{equation*}
1 + 4 + 7 + \ldots + (3n-2) = 2n(3n-1).
\end{equation*}

I immediately got stuck on the base case with $n=1$ because the following should be true: $1 = 2 \cdot 1 \cdot (3 \cdot 1 - 1) = 2 \cdot 2$ which is clearly not the case. However the exercise says to prove the given relation, not to check if it is correct, which is why I have elected to make this post to see if I am missing any obvious thing.

Comment: It should  be $\frac{n(3n-1)}{2}$.

Comment: Consulted the errata after reading your comment, you're right! Thank you!

Comment: You are welcome.

Comment: @AndréNicolas better as an answer.

Comment: @SufyanNaeem: Hard to know,  Maybe if I had something of significance to say about the induction proof. But the $2n(3n-1)$ is just a typo.

Comment: See also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/286312/proof-by-induction-that-sum-i-1n-3i-2-fracn3n-12

Answer (score 3):

First of all, the claim is wrong. A direct proof shows that.

The sequence $\{1,4,7,\ldots,3n-2\}$ is an arithmetic progression with common difference $3$ and there are $n$ number of terms in it. So, the sum of all the terms is:

$$\begin{align}S =1+4+7+\ldots+(3n-2)&=1+(1+3)+(1+6)+\ldots+(1+3(n-1))&\\ &=\sum_{i=1}^n(1)+\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}(3i)\\&=n+3\cdot\frac{(n-1)n}{2}=\frac{3n^2-n}{2}=\frac{n(3n-1)}{2}\neq 2n(3n-1)\end{align}$$

The "$\neq$" follows in general. Now, if you were to prove the corrected claim using induction, here's a hint for the inductive step:

$$\begin{align}S_{n+1} & =1+4+7+\ldots+(3n-2)+(3n+1)\\
&=S_n+(3n+1)\\
&=\frac{n(3n-1)}{2}+(3n+1)\tag{by I.H.}\\&=\frac{3n^2-n+6n+2}{2}\\&=\frac{3n^2+5n+2}{2}\\&=\frac{(n+1)(3n+2)}{2}\\
& =\ldots\end{align}$$

Answer (score 1):

You can always repeat Gauss:

$
\phantom{2}S = 1 + 4 + 7 + \cdots + (3n-2)
$

$
\phantom{2}S = (3n-2) + (3n-5) + (3n-8) + \cdots + 1
$

$
2S = (3n-1) + (3n-1) + (3n-1) + \cdots + (3n-1) = n(3n-1).
$

Answer (score 0):

$\displaystyle f_1(n) = \sum_{k\,=\,0}^{n-1} 3k\!+\!1,\ $ $\,f_2(n) = \dfrac{n(3n\!-\!1)}2\,$ are both solutions of $\,f(n\!+\!1)-f(n) = 3n\!+\!1,\,$ with equal initial condition $\,f(1)=1,\,$ so induction implies they remain equal for all $\,n,\,$ since the induction step is clear: $\, f_1(n\!+\!1) = f_1(n) + 3n\!+\!1 = f_2(n) + 3n\!+\!1 = f_2(n\!+\!1)$

**Remark** $\ $ This *uniqueness theorem* is a special case of *telescopy*. Further examples can be found in [prior posts.](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A242+telescopy+uniqueness)